# Change domain name based on user IP Address with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website that serves an international market and needs to use one of 3 different domain names based on the user's IP.

Here are the use cases:

- User IP from the UK, domain name appears as www.example.co.uk
- User IP from Australia, domain name appears as www.example.co.au
- All other IPs, domain name appears as www.example.com

In the answer, I do not need to know the exact IP addresses to use from each country, so you could use a generic IP in the answer - unless you want to go the extra mile and create this based on the actual IPs from the countries given.

Thanks!

Comment: you need to some scripting language and also get the remote ip of the visior and make a redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [install mod_geoip](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/mod_geoip2) and then you can use it using mod_rewrite:

```
# stuff for initializing mod_geoip
GeoIPEnable On
GeoIPDBFile /path/to/GeoIP.dat

RewriteEngine on

# rules per country
# User IP from the UK, domain name appears as www.example.co.uk
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^GB$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [R,L]

# User IP from Australia, domain name appears as www.example.co.au
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^AU$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example.co.au [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.example.co.au/$1 [R,L]

# All other IPs, domain name appears as www.example.com
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} !^GB$
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} !^AU$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier with a PHP code at the begining of your index file. `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`